# Error while rendering '&' in telerik html textbox

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

How can I handle an ampersand ("&") character in a Telerik HTML textbox?
While rendering, it's giving me an error. Also, does anybody know about any other character that may cause errors in an HTML textbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ampersand is a special character in HTML that specifies the start of an escape sequence (so you can do something like `&copy;` to get a copyright symbol, etc.).  If you want to display an ampersand you have to escape it.  So if you replace all ampersands with `&amp;`, that should take care of the error.

However, if there were ampersands in your input that were already escaped - like maybe your data had `&copy;` - you wouldn't want to escape that ampersand.  But if your data won't have any of these ampersands, a simple replace should be fine.

You also need to replace greater than and less than symbols (> and <) with `&gt;` and `&lt;` respectively.

Telerik talks about these limitations/issues on this page http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-items-html-text-box.html

> Also according to the HTML specification (and the general XML
>   specification as well) the "&", "<" and ">" characters are considered
>   special (markup delimiters), so they need to be encoded in order to be
>   treated as regular text. For example the "&" character can be escaped
>   with the "&" entity. More information on the subject you can find in
>   this w3.org article.